# Passing a string to the Windows command line

Tags: java, command-line, process, runtime.exec

Please see the code below

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
rt.exec("cmd /c start");
String[] cmd = {"LogParser", "Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application" };
rt.exec(cmd);
```

It opens the command window but the strings are not passed in after opening. Can someone tell me why this code won't place the strings into the command window?

Comment: They are executed as separate commands, they are not related just because you executed one before the other.

Comment: You are nowhere near a solution. I think your best bet is to create a text file with those commands and make `LogParser` accept commands from it.

Comment: Ok - but if I put them all into one string like

Comment: String[] cmd = {"cmd /c start", "LogParser", "Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application" }; the compiler doesn't like it

Comment: By the way, be sure to escape the backslashes: `"Select top 10 * into c:\\temp\\test9.csv from application"`.

Answer (score 2):

The option **/C** means: `Carries out the command  specified by the string and then terminates.`

So the other command is handled as a separated one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OutputStreamWriter` and write to the input stream of the process created.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /K start") ;
Writer w = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
w.append(yourCommandHere);
```

Also, the reason for using /K :

> /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.

Reference : http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: ...and this will fail because `cmd` completes immediately after spawning a separate process.

Comment: What will happen with your proposal is that `w` will append to `cmd`s standard input, instead of `LogParser`s -- which you don`t even involve in any way.

Comment: I think this is barking up the right tree, but what is needed is `"LogParser"` instead of `"cmd /K start"`. Then the output stream can be used to communicate with the LogParser process.  If the OP wants the LogParser to run in a separate cmd window, though, that ain't going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment - 'They are executed as separate commands, they are not related just because you executed one before the other'

From the `Runtime.exec( string )` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5b%5d)) -

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.

You need to chain the commands together to get `cmd` to process your command, I believe you need to use the `\k` flag to specify what commands you need executed on the command line.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
String start = "cmd /k ";
String cmd = "LogParser;\n" Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application";
rt.exec(start + cmd);
```

Not tested as I don't have windows, but it should be similar to this.

Comment: OP needs the `select` command passed as typed input to `LogParser`.

Comment: Ok I tried this & compiles fine but nothing seems to happen      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
          String start = "cmd /k ";
             String cmd = "LogParser";
             String cmd2 = "Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application";
             rt.exec(start + cmd + cmd2);

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd /c", "LogParser",
        "Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application" };
rt.exec(cmd);
```

Find more info about the `exec` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: `select...` is a command accepted through the standard input by `LogParser`.

Comment: String[] cmd = { "cmd /c", "LogParser",
        "Select top 10 * into c:\temp\test9.csv from application" };This returns a compile error on execution (cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to start a process as you do in your first two lines of code, but don't use `start` because that spawns a separate process and returns immediately. Use just `LogParser` instead, or whatever will make your `LogParser` process start without involving `cmd`. After that you need to retrieve the `OutputStream` of the `Process` object created by `exec` and write your `select` command into it. You will also need to read from the `Process`s `InputStream` to see the response. None of this will be visible in a separate command-prompt window; you'll need to process everything through Java and it will involve some multithreading as well.

Comment: Thanks Marko. you seem to know the most about this issue. I would assume your solution works but that sound difficult to say the least notwithstanding the fact I have 3 months Java experince to my name

Comment: Try to see if you can make `LogParser` take your `select` as an argument. That would make things a lot simpler. Failing that, see if you can make it read its commands from a file. Maybe you could also try something like `echo "select ..." | LogParser`.